# Dynamically created input file field not displaying image in canvas on change() call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am currently working on a project where I want to display image in canvas with watermark on change method of dynamically created input file field. but it is works sometimes and sometimes not. Don't know what's wrong in my code.

I just want my image with watermark.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#inputGenerator", function() {
  var newInput = '<input type = "file" onchange="generateThumbnail(this)">';
  $("#wrapper").append(newInput);
});

function generateThumbnail(mainElement) {
  let FR = new FileReader();
  FR.addEventListener("load", function(innerElement) {

    var virtualCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    virtualCanvas.setAttribute("width", "320");
    virtualCanvas.setAttribute("height", "310");
    var context = virtualCanvas.getContext('2d');

    var art = new Image(); // Create new img element
    art.addEventListener("load", function() {
      context.drawImage(art, 0, 0, 320, 310);
    }, false);
    art.src = innerElement.target.result;
    console.log(innerElement.target.result);

    var logo = new Image(); // Create new img element
    logo.addEventListener("load", function() {
      context.drawImage(logo, 0, 0, 200, 100);
      jpegUrl = virtualCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", .70);
      $("#outcome").attr("src", jpegUrl);
    }, false);
    logo.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";

  });
  FR.readAsDataURL(mainElement.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <button type="button" id="inputGenerator">Add Input</button>
  <img src="" id="outcome">
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet where it works absolutely fine for me. Can you please check the console for errors when the code fails, and edit the question to include that information. Also note that an example of an image that does not work would be helpful, as the issue may be to do with the image encoding.

Comment: Thanks rory for editing, but why this code is not working when I choose the  image second time?